# "feline" is to "cat" as "???" is to "monkey"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been unable to think of a word which describes this. Does someone know the answer? Is it *simian*?

Comment: Yes it is simian.  You answered your own question

Comment: Does a word2vec answer this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer  is of course *simian*. [Wiktionary has](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/simian):

> ### Simian
>
> #### Etymology
>
> From Latin *sīmia* ‎(“ape, monkey”), from Ancient Greek σιμός ‎(*simós*, “snub-nosed”).
>
> #### Adjective
>
> 1. Of or pertaining to apes; apely.
> 2. Bearing resemblance to an ape.
>
> #### Noun
>
> 1. An ape or monkey, especially an anthropoid.

All more precise terms are used only by specialists. So for example *catarrhine* refers to Old World simians, including both apes and monkeys and people who have colds, while *platyrrhine, platyr(r)hinian* refers to New World monkeys.

As you see, finding a monkeylike adjective (other than [*monkeylike* itself](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monkeylike)) that excludes apes is going to be hard because what we call *monkeys* is actually a polyphyletic group.

Comment: Now we post answers saying essentially 'Yes, and here is the research you should have done'?

Comment: *and people who have colds* ... LOL